# WeakHashMap vs HashMap

Tags: java, weakhashmap

In the following code example when keys are set to null and `System.gc()` is called, the `WeakHashMap` loses all mappings and is emptied.

```
class WeakHashMapExample {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Key k1 = new Key("Hello");
    Key k2 = new Key("World");
    Key k3 = new Key("Java");
    Key k4 = new Key("Programming");

    Map<Key, String> wm = new WeakHashMap<Key, String>();


    wm.put(k1, "Hello");
    wm.put(k2, "World");
    wm.put(k3, "Java");
    wm.put(k4, "Programming");
    k1=null;
    k2=null;
    k3=null;
    k4=null;
    System.gc();
    System.out.println("Weak Hash Map :"+wm.toString());

}

}

class Key{

private String key;

public Key(String key) {
    this.key=key;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return this.key.equals((String)obj);
}
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return key.hashCode();
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return key;
}

}
```

`Output: Weak Hash Map :{}`

When `WeakHashMap` is used along with `HashMap` and keys are set to null, the `WeakHashMap` doesn't lose its key-value mappings.

```
class WeakHashMapExample {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Key k1 = new Key("Hello");
    Key k2 = new Key("World");
    Key k3 = new Key("Java");
    Key k4 = new Key("Programming");

    Map<Key, String> wm = new WeakHashMap<Key, String>();
    Map<Key, String> hm=new HashMap<Key, String>();

    wm.put(k1, "Hello");
    wm.put(k2, "World");
    wm.put(k3, "Java");
    wm.put(k4, "Programming");

    hm.put(k1, "Hello");
    hm.put(k2, "World");
    hm.put(k3, "Java");
    hm.put(k4, "Programming");
    k1=null;
    k2=null;
    k3=null;
    k4=null;
    System.gc();
    System.out.println("Weak Hash Map :"+wm.toString());
    System.out.println("Hash Map :"+hm.toString());
}

}

class Key{

private String key;

public Key(String key) {
    this.key=key;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return this.key.equals((String)obj);
}
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return key.hashCode();
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return key;
}

}
```

Output: 
         `Weak Hash Map :{Java=Java, Hello=Hello, World=World, Programming=Programming}`
         `Hash Map :{Programming=Programming, World=World, Java=Java, Hello=Hello}`

My question is why doesn't the `WeakHashMap` lose its entries in the second code example even after the keys are discarded?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A [`WeakHashMap`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/WeakHashMap.java) discards entries when the key is no longer strongly reachable from live code. Since the [`HashMap`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java) maintains a hard reference to the keys, the keys are still reachable and the `WeakHashMap` doesn't discard the entries.

The point is that the behavior has to do with references to the key objects, not to the value of any variable that might have at one time had a reference to the keys.

Comment: I never even thought of variables as just containing a pointer too, that's very informative to know, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

An *object* must be discarded everywhere else, and then the WeakHashMap clears that object. Like a WeakReference its purpose is to remember an object if it is still in use. Without causing a memory leak forever holding an object.

In your example set `hm = null;` to see the magic of the WeakHashMap cleaning up.

Comment: yes, setting `hm=null` before `System.gc()` does clears the WHM. Thanks, I got it.

Answer (score 3):

You have set `null` on pointers `k1,k2,k3,k4` but `HashMap` and `WeakHashMap` still contains references to those `Keys`. And because `HashMap` is containing reference, actual instances of Keys are not deleted by GC. `WeakHashMap` still prints all of them.

Try run this example only with `HashMap` -> even that you've nulled out those references `HashMap` will still keep them.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
class WeakHashMapExample {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Key k1 = new Key("Hello");
    Key k2 = new Key("World");
    Key k3 = new Key("Java");
    Key k4 = new Key("Programming");

    Map<Key, String> hm=new HashMap<Key, String>();   
    hm.put(k1, "Hello");
    hm.put(k2, "World");
    hm.put(k3, "Java");
    hm.put(k4, "Programming");
    k1=null;
    k2=null;
    k3=null;
    k4=null;
    System.gc();
    System.out.println("Hash Map :"+hm);

    System.out.println("Same thing with weakHash Map - "); 

    k1 = new Key("Hello");
    k2 = new Key("World");
    k3 = new Key("Java");
    k4 = new Key("Programming");

    Map<Key, String> wm = new WeakHashMap<Key, String>();

    wm.put(k1, "Hello");
    wm.put(k2, "World");
    wm.put(k3, "Java");
    wm.put(k4, "Programming");
    k1=null;
    k2=null;
    k3=null;
    k4=null;
    System.gc();
    System.out.println("Weak Hash Map :"+wm);
}

}

class Key{

private String key;

public Key(String key) {
    this.key=key;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return this.key.equals((String)obj);
}
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return key.hashCode();
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return key;
}

public void finalize() 
{ 
   System.out.println("Finalize method is called"); 
} 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

HashMap dominates gc(garbage collector).

gc dominates WeakHashMap.

Even though we set null on k1,k2,k3,k4 gc wont remove from HashMap where as gc removes them all and provides us empty map for WeakHashMap hence the name WeakHashMap

Answer (score 0):

while JVM runs garbage collector and it found an object having no reference variable then it will destroy it but while that object act as key in HashMap then garbage collector won't destroy it. In the case of WeakHashmap it will destroy object even if it act as key if it is not having reference. In above code even  k1,k2,k3,k4=null

but because these objects are key in hashmap they won't be destroyed by garbage collection.
if you want to destroy it just remove them from Hashmap by
setting hm=null;
then System.gc(); will destroy k1,k2,k3,k4